# cut a dataframe by two columns and calculate mean value of third column for each piece

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, cut

Goal: Take a DataFrame, group by two columns of that DataFrame, calculate the mean of other columns, and return a dataframe. What should I do?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
md = {"group1": [1, 2, 4, 5],
  "group2": [2, 3, 5, 6],
  "var1":[343, 345, 567, 569],
  "wt":[1.2, 1.3, 1.8, 1.9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(md)
```

This is what I wish to get:

```
group1  group2        mean of var1   mean of wt
1-3       3-5         344            1.25
2-4       4-6         568            1.85
```

Thank you for your time to help!

Comment: What is the logic in making the first 2 rows go into one group, and the bottom 2 rows into another group? Why the `group1 = 1-3, 2-4` in the output? Same question with `group2`?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I was trying to show that the first and second columns are grouped by their value.. For group1, if the value >3 it goes to first row of the new table. and likewise for group 2. Hope that explains better.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to create two categories in each group. One where `group<i> <= 3` and another one where `group<i> > 3`. So, my suggestion is :

```
# Make category column for the first group
df.loc[df['group1'] <= 3,'group1_category'] = "1-3"
df['group1_category'].fillna("3 <", inplace=True)

# Make category column for the second group
df.loc[df['group1'] <= 3,'group2_category'] = "1-3"
df['group2_category'].fillna("3 <", inplace=True)


result = df.groupby(['group1_category','group2_category']).mean()[['var1','wt']]
```

This will give this output :

```
group1_category  group2_category        mean of var1   mean of wt
1-3              1-3                    344            1.25
3 <              3 <                    568            1.85
```